# mediaelement.js: place controls below video

Tags: controls, positioning, mediaelement.js

simple implementation of mediaelement.js - 'cause I am a simple guy.

I'd like to place the controls below the video, not merely at the bottom, within the video. As far as I can tell, the only parameter that deals with controls is alwaysShowControls: true/false.

Is there a way to position the controls outside & below the video?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this with CSS, by creating some space below the media element container and pushing the controls (which already have `position:abdolute`) into that space. You do need to know the height of your control bar to do this. For instance, if it's 30px high:

```
.mejs-container {
  /* Create some space below the player for the controls to move into. */
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.mejs-container .mejs-controls {
  /* Move the controls into the space below the player. */
  bottom: -30px;
}
```